# How to load an array based on selected cell value from previous controller in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I'm trying to build something close to the way the note app works but when you select the note instead of text you have a `collectionView` with cells loaded from an array.

Say I have two viewControllers connected to each other.
The `firstViewController` has a `collectionView` loaded with the note names and upon selecting a note it will segue to the `secondViewController` that will load the array for that note.

I have a hard time understanding the logic... Do I work with `NSUserDefaults` and create an `objectForKey` for every note or do I create a new array for every note.
How would I store these?

**firstViewController**

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate {

 var objects = Array<NSDate>()


 @IBAction func insertNewObject(sender: AnyObject) {

    objects.insert(NSDate(), atIndex: 0)
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
    collectionView.insertItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath])
}

 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){

storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("secondtView") as! SecondViewController

//How do I proceed here? 

}
}
```

**secondViewController**

```
var myArray:[[AnyObject]] = []
class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate {


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("myArray") != nil) {
    myArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("myArray") as! [[AnyObject]]
    }
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      myArray.count
}



 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell 
 cell.cellLabel.text = myArray[indexPath.row][0] as? String
 return cell 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough time to write out the actually solution so ill just give you the steps that I would take to solve your problem and then you can take it from there.

First, I would use core data. Have a note entity that has note name, note message, time, and what ever other attributes that you think are important.

With your data structure in place, when ever the user taps on a view in your collection view save that value as currently_selcted or something in NSUserDefaults.

Then go to your second view controller and load that currently_selcted value. THEN look up the relevant information in your coredata data structure.

[here is a link on using core data](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started)

[and here is one on using NSUserDefaults](http://www.codingexplorer.com/nsuserdefaults-a-swift-introduction/), hope this helped

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are over thinking it.

Why not just pass the data to the second view using the prepareForSegue method? So if you have a title, note and a date in an array (all of this data would be initialized in your separate object class) you would just pass that array from one view controller to another.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "SecondView" {
            if let destVC = segue.destinationViewController as? secondViewController {
                if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                    let object = objects[indexPath.row]
                    destVC.object = object
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And then you just create a variable inside your secondViewController class called "object" to catch the array.

I could be completely off due to not completely understanding what you are trying to do in the app.